# How to show tooltip value of all data falling on the same axis in chart js?

Tags: tooltip, chart.js

I have used line chart from chart.js. The line chart contains two data set. What i am trying to achieve is, when a user hovers on one of the data points it must also show the data of the another data set falling on the same axis just like the example in Chart js:
[image]

But my chart's tooltip looks like:
[image]

I want to show the number of checkin and apointment both in the same tooltip when it is hovered in any one of the data of the same axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the below configuration in the tooltip.

```
options: {
   tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
    position: 'nearest'
  }
}
```

More tooltip examples [here](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/interactions.html)